# Trouble with Prime connection

Tags: java

The problem below was given in one of my exams and was asked to solve the following problem using Java only.

The problem is, I got stuck in the part where the program is supposed to return the given non-negative integer as an array of digits. Can anyone provide a solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Two positive numbers A and B are said to be connected (denoted by "A ↔ B") if one of these conditions holds:
(1) A and B have the same length and differ in exactly one digit; for example, 123 ↔ 173.
(2) Adding one digit to the left of A (or B) makes B (or A); for example, 23 ↔ 223 and 123 ↔ 23.

We call a prime P a 2's relative if there exists a chain of connected primes between 2 and P and no prime in the chain exceeds P.

For example, 127 is a 2's relative. One of the possible chains is shown below:
2 ↔ 3 ↔ 13 ↔ 113 ↔ 103 ↔ 107 ↔ 127
However, 11 and 103 are not 2's relatives.

Let F(N) be the sum of the primes ≤ N which are not 2's relatives.
We can verify that F(103) = 431 and F(104) = 78728.

Find F(107).

**Edited: my part**
I am sorry I don't carbon copy remember my solution as I don't have my results given to me. But just for the sake of this question, I think the part where it was supposed to return non-negative number, I had something like this -

```
private static int[] toDigits(int n) {
    if (n < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    int[] temp = new int[10];
    int len = 0;
    do {
        temp[len] = n % 9;
        n /= 9;
        len++;
    } while (n > 0);
```

Comment: That's a Project Euler problem pasted here

Comment: `Can anyone provide a solution to this?` No, that's not how this site works. Show your effort and be detailed about the specific problem you're encountering.

Comment: Should we answer this question though? [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307197/should-we-avoid-answering-questions-with-a-negative-score)

Comment: @jiltedpotato, I suppose if you have an answer for it, go for it

Comment: @MachineLove Do you still have the code you used in your exam? If so, share `the part where the program is supposed to return the given non-negative integer as an array of digits` and we could try to help you figure out the problem?

Comment: @downshift I am sorry I don't carbon copy remember my solution as I don't have my results given to me. But just for the sake of this question, I think the part where it was supposed to return non-negative number, I had something like the one I edited above.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;


public final class infinitybyone implements TestSolution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new infinitybyone().run());
    }


    private static final int LIMIT = Library.pow(10, 7);

    public String run() {
        boolean[] isPrime = Library.listPrimality(LIMIT);
        int[] pathMax = new int[isPrime.length];
        Arrays.fill(pathMax, Integer.MAX_VALUE);


        Queue<IntPair> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
        queue.add(new IntPair(2, 2));
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            IntPair item = queue.remove();
            int n = item.b;
            int pmax = item.a;
            if (pmax >= pathMax[n]) {

                continue;
            }

            pathMax[n] = pmax;

            int[] digits = toDigits(n);
            int[] tempDigits = digits.clone();
            for (int i = 0; i < tempDigits.length; i++) {  
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) { 
                    tempDigits[i] = j;
                    int m = toNumber(tempDigits);
                    int nextPmax = Math.max(m, pmax);
                    if (m < isPrime.length && isPrime[m] && nextPmax < pathMax[m])
                        queue.add(new IntPair(nextPmax, m));
                }
                tempDigits[i] = digits[i];  
            }
        }

        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < isPrime.length; i++) {
            if (isPrime[i] && pathMax[i] > i)
                sum += i;
        }
        return Long.toString(sum);
    }
    private static int[] toDigits(int n) {
        if (n < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        //************This is PROBABLY where you made the error************

        int[] temp = new int[11];
        int len = 0;
        do {
            temp[len] = n % 10;
            n /= 10;
            len++;
        } while (n > 0);

        int[] result = new int[len + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
            result[i] = temp[len - i];
        return result;
    }


    private static int toNumber(int[] digits) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int x : digits)
            result = result * 10 + x;
        return result;
    }



    private static class IntPair implements Comparable<IntPair> {

        public final int a;
        public final int b;


        public IntPair(int a, int b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }


        public int compareTo(IntPair other) {
            return Integer.compare(a, other.a);
        }

    }

}
```

I can't really tell where you messed up but at least from the code you shared, tell me why would you use `10` instead of `11`? It should extract `base-10` in little endian.